# Do flower Pikmin perform tasks faster?

Tags: pikmin

In Pikmin 1, Pikmin with flowers on their head move faster than Pikmin with buds. Does this speed increase also apply when performing tasks or carrying objects?

For example, will a flower Pikmin act faster than bud Pikmin when carrying a ship part, building a bridge, or attacking an enemy?